# How to mark a generic delegate to accept null values?

Tags: c#, nullable

With [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#nullable-reference-types) activated, how to authorize a `Func` parameter to be null ?

```
public void Test<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> func)
{
    var r = func(default); // default may be null, I got an error.
}
```

Currently I solve this with:

```
public void Test<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> func)
{
    var r = func(default!); // null it is !
}
```

But I just want to mark `func` has accepting null in input:

```
public void Test<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn?, TOut> func) // do not work
{
    var r = func(default);
}
```

I also tried to build my own delegate:

```
public delegate TOut Dunc<in TIn, out TOut>(TIn? in);
```

But then I got an error : please mark TIn as class or struct.

Comment: Did you mean to put the ? after `TIn` instead of `TOut` in the third code-block or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Joelius fixed thanks.

Comment: Could you not just write it as
`var r = func(default(TIn));` or am I missing something?

Comment: What error are you getting on the second one? I would imagine that, without any contraints on `TIn`, you shouldn't have to do anything to indicate that it could be a null reference type, as the type is defined by the caller.

Comment: @vonludi, I could, it's the same thing since c# 7.4 or something

Comment: @RufusL no errors on the second one (has I said, it works), but I don't want to put the '!' at each call, I want the delegate / func to accept null.

Comment: have you tried setting it eual null in your func parameters public void Test<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn?, TOut> func = null)

Comment: Care to show us what `Func`s you want to use with this `Test` function? It seems to work just fine for me as seen [here](https://repl.it/repls/ScholarlySatisfiedParentheses). Or is this explicitly about the usage of `default` without any parameters?

Comment: Because nullable references and nullable value types are different at the runtime level, you can't declare one delegate type to eat both of them. You can have two separate delegate types (and hence two overloads), one constrained to `class` and one constrained to `struct`. Clumsy, but that's the way it has to be for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @vonludi, I think Nullable reference type is not activated in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### edit

The code below (from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3471#issuecomment-735362794)) is now legal in C# 9

```
public T? GetDefault<T>()
{
    return default;
}
```

#### original answer

`T?` may have different meaning

- if `T` is a struct it's an alias for `Nullable<T>`
- if `T` is a class it's a sugar to add a `NullableAttribute` to tell the compiler that we allow a null reference here.

To Mark a generic method or delegate that some parameters or the returned value may be a null reference. We can force the generic type to be a reference and use `?`

```
T? Result<T>() where T : class;
```

Or we can use the [notnull](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#notnull-constraint) constraint that have been build for such cases:

```
T? Result<T>() where T : notnull;
```